# Looping qgis:zonalstatistics using PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-2, zonal-statistics, loop

I'm looking for some Python + QGIS for the following:

```
import processing
for i in range (1,20):
    processing.runalg("qgis:zonalstatistics", "/folder/input/raster.tif",%i,
    "/folder/input/poly.shp","Var_%i",True, "/folder/output/zonalpoly_%i.shp"
```

The above BASH like example doesn't work, but if I substitute an integer in place of %i, the script runs correctly, so I know that the syntax is correct.

I'm a bit fuzzy on how to properly pass a variable into a string using Python and/or how to run a QGIS plugin from the built-in Python interpreter for QGIS.

Also, qgis:zonalstatistics calculates several summary statistics (mean, stddev, maximum, etc.) with no apparent means of specifying one or a few of these.

Is there a way of specifying just one, or a few?

It seems like a complete waste of processing time to calculate each if I'm only interested in one or a few measures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) string formatting:

It is a not a problem of QGIS or processing but a simple problem of string formatting in Python, look at [Python String Format](http://ebeab.com/2012/10/10/python-string-format/), for example.

```py
print  "Var_{}".format(3)
Var_3
# or old
print "Var_%s" % (1) 
Var_1
```

Script example 1:

```py
for i in range(1,20):
    processing.runalg("qgis:zonalstatistics", "/folder/input/raster.tif",i,"/folder/input/poly.shp","Var_{0}".format(i),True, "/folder/output/zonalpoly_{0}.shp".format(i))
```

Script example 2

```py
for i in range(1,20):
     processing.runalg("qgis:zonalstatistics","/folder/input/raster.tif",i,"/folder/input/poly.shp", "Var_%s" %i ,True, "/folder/output/zonalpoly_%s.shp"%i
```

2) But QGIS actually has also zonal statistics methods built into the API with Python bindings (look at [QGIS: How to calculate raster statistics for polygons?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23203/how-to-calculate-raster-statistics-for-polygons))

3) For the other question, no solution, look at  [Processing-Help: ZONAL STATISTICS](https://github.com/volaya/Processing-Help/blob/master/qgis/zonalstatistics.rst):

```py
processing.runalg("qgis:zonalstatistics", input_raster, band_number, input_vector, column_prefix, load_flag, output_layer)
```

Comment: Thanks! I've managed to get the first example running, although it was missing a right bracket at the end. Example two also seems to be missing a bracket. Unfortunately, running example two gets me a `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'dict' and 'int'`

Comment: Option 2) isn't really an option as I believe the built-in API version of zonal statistics doesn't allow for selecting an individual band within a file. If it does, it doesn't seem obvious to me how it's implemented. Good to know though.

Comment: Also missing a 0 in `"Var_{}"`. Should be `"Var_{0}"` in the first example. Example 1 definitely works. Let me know if you can figure out the issue for Example 2.

Comment: `Var_{0}`in Python 2.6, `Var_{}`in Python 2.7