# Extract results from zonal statistics

Tags: qgis, zonal-statistics

I am trying to calculate mean slope in given polygons. I first interpolate my (x,y,z) data to create a raster file and use the terrain analysis tool to calculate slope.
Then I use the zonal statitistics to obtain slope within each polygon ([how-to-calculate-raster-statistics-for-polygons](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23203/%22how-to-calculate-raster-statistics-for-polygons%22)).

I have two issues.

1. The results are appended to the polygon shapefile. Is there a way to extract the results as a text file ?
2. Apparently I get only one value (i.e. one mean, one max, one median, etc) while I have 6 polygons. My polygons overlay but I get this problem even if they do not. How can I have separate results from each polygon ?

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question per question.

Answer (score 3):

Are you specifying a zonal field?  This is the field that contains a name or id for each polygon that defines an individual zone. You must specify this in order to calculate individual zonal stats.

Comment: My initial WKT file has id. Then I export it to a shapefile. But the box where I specify layers for the zonal statistics does not have any entry for ids, only "raster layer", "band", polygon layer, "prefix" and statistics. Where can I add it ?