# Get value of a raster layer from actual extent

Tags: raster, pyqgis

I would like to create a plugin where I could use the values of a raster layer from the actual extent, to do some tricks.

For example if I have a raster which is a box [x,y,width,height] : [0,0,1000,1000], I zoom on it to see the AOI so my actual extent begin [50,50,100,100] (for example), how can I use it these values, without reloading the entire image ?

I would like to do really fast calcul (no reloading, no saving, just displaying with vector calcul => Instant on small area).

I can get the value of one pixel doing it like that :

```
layer = iface.mapCanvas().layers()[0]
extent = iface.mapCanvas().extent()

layer.dataProvider().identify(QgsPoint(extent.xMinimum(), extent.yMinimum()), QgsRaster.IdentifyFormatValue).results()[1]
```

Is that a way to us QgsRectangle on identify and not QgsPoint ? Because I would like to get the value of the extent rectangle and not from a point only, without doing a for loop of course to fill an array.

Comment: I believe that Zonal statistics does what you want and if not, you could perhaps improve that instead of creating your own plugin.

Comment: Actually Zonal statistics, don't get the values from an actual extent of a raster but from all the raster while Reloading it. That's why it take so much time to calcul on big TIF.

Comment: I thought that it is analyzing just the areas which are as polygons on the polygon layer.

Comment: Nop, the extent is the coordinates of windows, of the datas you see on the QGIS window

Comment: I just want to get the values which are display on the screen. If you zoom on a raster, on a small area, I want to use only these values, not all the datas of the raster.

Comment: At least it used to compute statistics by the polygons on the polygon layer https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23203/how-to-calculate-raster-statistics-for-polygons. You can also try the suggested Saga method.

Comment: I updated my post, to ask how to get value from a rectangle and not from a point.